# What does grep -cE ">" myfile.txt do?

Tags: command-line, scripts, grep, find, database

I understand how to use grep; however, I am having trouble understanding the function of using ">" in my command?

Comment: thank you! @steeldriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character `>` on its own doesn't have any special significance in either a basic or an extended regular expression, so both

```
grep -Ec ">" myfile.txt
```

and

```
grep -c ">" myfile.txt
```

count the number of lines in `myfile.txt` that contain the character `>`